# Login JSP and servlet connect to database

Tags: database, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP login page within which I'm taking in username and password and they get passed to my servlet, which validates them using my users table in psaviour database, and then on success or failure, should forward them to the welcome page or back to the login.

Yet I'm stuck trying to connect to my database from my checklogin servlet.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


     @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/checkLogin"})
     public class checkLogin extends HttpServlet {

        private final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/psaviour";
        private final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        private final String USER = "root";
        private final String PASS = "root";
        Connection conn;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;



    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
    response)
     throws ServletException, IOException {
      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();    
      String username = request.getParameter("username");//.toString();
      String passkey = request.getParameter("passkey");//.toString();

      try {
          Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
          try {
              conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
              stmt=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'username' = 
              ? AND 'passkey' = ?");
              stmt.setString(1, username);
              stmt.setString(2, passkey);
              rs = stmt.executeQuery();
          } catch (SQLException e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException ce){
              ce.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      while (rs.next()){
          //need to point to my welcome.jsp page or 
      }
       //otherwise reload login page....  
   }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if (rs.next()){
    //need to point to my welcome.jsp page or 
    RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("/welcome.jsp");
    dispatch.forward(request, response);
} else {
    //otherwise reload login page....  
    request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Authentication failure!");
    response.sendRedirect("/login");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (rs.next()){
   response.sendRedirect("success.html");
   return;
} else {
    //otherwise reload login page...
    response.sendRedirect("login.html");
    return;
}
```